# Soap Client dont throw on exception

Tags: php, soap

i want when my wsdl server is down, SoapClient Throw to Exception, can any body help to me ?

```
function a()
{
    try
    {
        $wsdl = @new SoapClient( 'http://somedomain.com' );
        return true;
    } catch( Exception  $sf )
    {
        return false;
    }
}
var_dump( a() );
```

i want result of my code is : false but when server down, my page is only white and has not any output

Comment: Why the `@` if you want to actually catch exceptions?

Comment: @Brad : if remove @ just return errors, but i want found in programming that SoapClient Successfull Or Not ?

Comment: I don't think you are going to get an exception on the constructor.  For SoapClient, doesn't it just set the object to use the URL?  Correct me if I'm remembering incorrectly, but I don't believe SoapClient actually makes any calls until you call a function later.

Comment: @bread: somedomain.com is for example, you think my wsdl are www.google.com, i want when google.com is down, SoapClient Go on Exception, but it not, Of course i find a trick for it, we should fopen before new SoapClient to found that server is down or up

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried catching a SoapFault Exception instead of just a regular Exception?

```
    function a()
    {
        try
        {
            $wsdl = @new SoapClient( 'http://somedomain.com' );
            return true;
        } catch( SoapFault  $sf )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    var_dump( a() );
```

Comment: Ok then, try adding "array("exceptions" => 1)" as a second argument to the constructor call. Without the outer " of course.

Comment: The full line should read 

$wsdl = @new SoapClient( 'http://somedomain.com',array("exceptions"=>1));